# python create parent class the function as hashtable

Tags: python, hashtable

i want me class to be used as list, therefor i create Magic class

```
@dataclass
class Magic(Person):
    position = []

    def __new__(cls, pos, person):
        if pos < len(cls.position):
            return cls.position[pos]
        if pos == len(cls.position)+1:
            instance = cls.__new__(cls)# should create new class
            cls.position.append(instance)
            return instance
        else:
            raise Exception('out of bound')

    def __getitem__(self, pos):
        return self.position[pos]
```

this class extend Person class, that should contain the content

```
@dataclass
class Person(type):
    age: int = 1
```

finally I want to fill up the hash

```
a = Magic()
a[0].age = 5
print(a)
```

i understand that I should create an instance on the class, but do not understand how
ahh and i want that the hashtable will be created in order positions
that i could not create a[1].age =5 before a[0].age =5

clarify
While regular lists behave like:

```
>>> a = list()
>>> a[0] = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

if i write this code the result should be

```
>>> a = Magic(Person)
>>> a[0].age = 5
>>> print(a)
[Person(age=5)]
```

And the list should also enforce its indexes continuity:

```
>>> a = Magic(Person)
>>> a[1].age = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to do? The description is hard to follow.

Comment: What *problem are you trying to solve*? Please show an example of how you want to use the class, show what happens when you try doing that, and explain how that is different from what is supposed to happen.

Comment: Judging from the last pieces, you do not want to allow ``a[1]`` being set before ``a[0]`` – why not use a ``list`` instead of a ``dict`` then? The purpose of a ``dict``/"hashtable" is to allow *any* static key, regardless of pre-existing keys.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yep i got this at some point, but still this fill to me right now as extra

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. If you want ``Magic``/``position`` to behave exactly like a ``list``, why not *use* a ``list``?

Comment: my bad i need to change it, do you want me to refactor the question?

Comment: I don't know what *is* your question, so I cannot recommend whether it should be refactored or not.

Comment: i want to create a class a = MagicList(cls_type=Person) that when i assert a[0].age = 5 it will not throw error, and that result should be print(a) >>>[Person(age=5)]

Answer (score 0):

i think i solve it myself
on the start i wanted to use a method that i'm less familiar so i had allot of issues, but at last it work!

Person

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self) -> object:
        self.age = 10
```

MagicList

```
class MagicList(Person):

    def __init__(self):
        self.position = []
        Person.__init__(self)

    def __getitem__(self, key) -> int:
        if not self.position or len(self.position) == key:
            self.__setitem__(key)
            return self.position[key]
        elif len(self.position) > key:
            return self.position[key]
        return None

    def __setitem__(self, key):
        if not self.position:
            self.position.append(Person)
        elif len(self.position)-1 >= key:
            self.position[key] = Person

        elif len(self.position) == key and Person != None:
            self.position.append(Person)
```

and to check my code

```
a = MagicList(Person)
a[0].age = 5
print(a[0].age)
assert a[0].age == 5

a[1].age = 7
print(a[1].age)
assert a[0].age == 7

try:
    a[4].age = 11

except AttributeError as ex:
    print("Currect AttributeError age {}".format(ex))
```